# Manually calculating `false positive risk` (using Likelihood ratio and Bayes analysis)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, p-value, likelihood-ratio

The question is with reference to this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.04888.pdf

In the real life example on page 17-18, it is advised that the `false positive risk` is calculated using online calculator at http://fpr-calc.ucl.ac.uk/

How can `false positive risk` be calculated manually for this example? 
What exact formulae can we use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arXiv paper has now been published, at https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rsos.171085
The equations are all given in the appendices. There is a simple explicit form for the p-less-than result,  but the more relevant p-equals form is inconvenient by hand which is why I wrote the web calculator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is good to hear from original author. Your article is very informative and concepts are very clearly explained.

Comment: Pls see this question also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/474891/manually-calculating-false-negative-risk-using-likelihood-ratio-and-bayesian