# Manually calculating `false negative risk` (using Likelihood ratio and Bayesian analysis)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, p-value, likelihood-ratio

The question is with reference to this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.04888.pdf  and  https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rsos.171085

It give clearly how to calculate `false positive risk` or `false discovery risk`.
A real life example is also given on page 17-18

However, how can `false NEGATIVE risk` be calculated manually?
What exact formulae can we use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the link to my paper. I have been thinking of adding the false negative risk to my web calculator (but after 110 days of lockdown I'm having difficulty in concentrating).  Presumably it should be defined as
(false neg)/(false neg + true neg).

Incidentally, our web calculator at http://fpr-calc.ucl.ac.uk/ is down at the moment (a cock-up at UCL), but there is another copy at http://shiny.ieis.tue.nl/fpr_calc/

There are also later papers on the topic, in which I'm more explicit about the assumptions) at https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00031305.2018.1529622
and at https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsos.190819

Comment: Look forward to your method for estimating `false negative risk`. Many drugs have been found to have `non-significant` effect against COVID-19. It will be important to know false negative risk for these studies.

Comment: Of course it's always possible that the drugs don't work. The prior probability of a random drug being effective for a viral infection must be very low.

Comment: These are not random agents. They have some prior study indicating their likely efficacy. I would put prior probability as 2/3 or 0.67

Comment: That seems much too high to me. But we are both guessing. That's why I suggest citing, along with the p value and CI, the FPR_50 ie the value for a prior of 0.5. That's the nearest we can get to equipoise.

Comment: I want to focus on how to calculate False `NEGATIVE` Risk. Same principles as FPR will need to be applied to `power`?

Comment: For `power` varying from 0.8 to .95, FPR_50 (a prior of 0.5), will be only slightly higher than the observed p value.  FPR_50 is 0.058 if p value is 0.05 and power is 0.8 . Not much difference. Difference is even lesser for higher power values. (I hope my calculation is correct)

Comment: That calculation is right only if you use the p-less-than method of calculation of the likelihood ratio. That method is wrong, or at least inappropriate, for interpretation of a p value for a single experiment.  Who consider p values that have not been observed?  If you use the p-equals  method to calculate the likelihood ratio, the FPR_50 is not 0.058, but it is 0.26 -far bigger. e.g. see Fig 2 in https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rsos.171085#d3e628https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rsos.171085#d3e628

Comment: Both methods of calculation are given by our false positive risk calculator, At present the usual URL, http://fpr-calc.ucl.ac.uk/  is offline (thanks to a cockup by UCL) but you can access a back up copy at http://fpr-calc.ucl.ac.uk/fpr_calc/

Comment: From the graph, it appears that, for P<0.05, FPR with p-equal method, is almost linear. Hence, for this part, if a simple formula can be given, everyone can easily use it. Its acceptability will also increase as the current method of using online calculator is quite cumbersome. IMHO.

Comment: It's true that, for small enough p values, the log(FPR) vs log(observed p value) is more or less linear, but the position of the line will depend on all the values that you have to enter into the R scripts or the web calculator.  The web calculator was provided for those people for whom running an R script is "too cumbersome".  I doubt that it's possible to devise a simpler way of doing the calculations.

Comment: P-less-than method seems simple: LR = pval / power;  OR = priorORHo * LR; FDR = OR/(1+OR) . What are similar steps for P-equal method?

Comment: @mso The explicit calculations are specified in the appendices of my papers.